# Azure DevOps submodule addressing

Tags: azure-devops

In my organization, some people use ssh: while others use https: when accessing Git on Azure DevOps.

This causes a problem with submodules, as the .gitmodules file usually holds the full URL to the submodules repository (which obviously are different for https: and ssh:).

You can also use relative paths in .gitmodules though. If the submodule is another repository in the same project, the URL is simply `../{repository}`.

If the submodule is in another project in the same Azure Devops organization, the URL is simply `../../{project}/{repository}`, right?

Well, for ssh: the answer is yes, but for https: the URL unfortunately is `../../../{project}/_git/{repository}`.

Why on earth MS designed it like this, is beyond me.

My question is: Does anyone have a solution for this? Is Git URL rewrite a feasible solution?

PS. If you think this is less than optimal design by MS, you might want to upvote my suggestion to MS here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Drop-the-_git-in-the-Git-https-URL/1643086?space=21&entry=suggestion

PPS. If you clone a repository via https: and successively modify your .gitmodules url to `../../{project}/{repository}`, it apparently works. But you wont be able to clone it again via https: with this modified .gitmodules.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same problem, so I thought I would post my solution.

In my case I am the only Linux user in my organization and the default here is to use the HTTPS relative paths.
I then convert the paths with a wrapper so that they can be fetched with ssh instead.

in .gitconfig I have added

```
[core]
        sshCommand = /home/user/.bin/work_git_ssh.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
#/home/user/.bin/work_git_ssh.sh
set -euo pipefail
args=()

org="your-org"

for i in "${@}"; do
   args+=( "$( echo "$i" | sed -E "s+v3/([^/]*)/_git/+v3/$org/\1/+g" )" )
done

exec ssh "${args[@]}"
```

There are probably some cases where this does not work, but it is good enough for me.

cheers